# Insert View between ViewPager2 Elements in android?

Tags: android

I am using a ViewPager2 element with several items inside.
Is it possible, and how, to set a separate View (with just an image for example) between each element of the ViewPager2?

So at the end I have something like

-> image | element 1 | image | element 2 | image | element 3 | image

my fallback solution, which I currently not prefere, is to include the separate view inside the viewpager, between the elements as an own element. but this solutions seems bad.

Comment: recyclerview is good for such use-case.

Comment: do you have any example, i have no idea, how to get start into